# How getting the unitarized irreducible representations with GAP?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, gap

The function `IrreducibleRepresentations` on GAP gives non-necessarily unitary representations, for example:

```
gap> R:=IrreducibleRepresentations(SymmetricGroup(5));;
gap> m:=(2,3)^R[5];;
gap> Display(m);
[ [   1,   0,   0,   0,   0 ],
  [   0,   1,   0,   0,   0 ],
  [   0,   0,   0,   0,   1 ],
  [  -1,  -1,   0,  -1,   0 ],
  [   0,   0,   1,   0,   0 ] ]
```

A unitary representation of the transposition `(2,3)` is supposed to be self-adjoint, but the matrix above is not.

*Question*: How getting the unitarized irreducible representations with GAP?

Comment: There is no built-in function that tries to find unitary representations. One could have $G$ act on the space of forms (via the representation), find the fixed forms, and see to map one of them to the standard unitary form, but none of this has predefined functions either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithm by Dixon that is used by `IrreducibleRepresentationDixon` allows for unitary representations. The calculations however depend on square roots being available (otherwise the calculation can fail), and can involve rather awkward cyclotomics.

In case anybody cannot wait, I put the relevant code under:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ag7yd3mom1ulta/unitarydixon.g?dl=0

Read in the file with `Reread` and call `IrreducibleRepresentationDixon` with the `unitary` option:

```
gap> R:=IrreducibleRepresentationsDixon(SymmetricGroup(5):unitary);;
gap> m:=(2,3)^R[5];;
gap> m*GaloisCyc(TransposedMat(m),-1);  # unitary, jay!
[ [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ] ]
gap> 10*m[2][3]; # ugly !
-E(60)^7-E(60)^11+E(60)^19+E(60)^23+E(60)^31-E(60)^43+E(60)^47-E(60)^59
```

Comment: This now seems to be in GAP 4.7.5, but I don't think it works fully: using `SL(2,5)` as the base group, both 2-dimensional representations are not unitary. Any idea what's wrong?
Here is the GAP code:
`gap> R:=IrreducibleRepresentationsDixon(SL(2,5):unitary);;`
`gap> m:=GeneratorsOfGroup(SL(2,5))[1]^R[2];;`
`gap> m*GaloisCyc(TransposedMat(m),-1);`