# How unitarize an irreducible representation of a finite group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group acting irreducibly on the space $V$.  $$\psi : G \to Aut(V)$$

*Question:* How unitarize the representation $V$?

I'm looking for a computable process.

Comment: Averaging: given one inner product $\langle,\rangle$, define $(v,w)=\sum_{g\in G} \langle \psi(g)(v),\psi(g)(w)\rangle$.

Comment: That works, but it would not be very practical for a large group. It is easier to compute the matrix of a fixed form as a module isomorphism between the module and the dual of its complex conjugate.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Is it possible to implement your method on GAP? In fact, for any (non necessarily unitary) irreducible representation given by the GAP function IrreducibleRepresentations, I would like the unitary matrices of the unitarized representation of  the group.

Comment: Possibly, but I don't think I want to get involved in detailed discussions about that! There are various practical issues, such as what field you are going to compute in, and if you want to diagonalize the unitary form matrix then you will need to compute eigenvalues, and eigenvectors, etc. You could try asking on the GAP forum.

Comment: In fact you don't need to compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Although you will still need to compute square roots of real cyclotomics at the end, as I mentioned in GAP forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1131010/84284) of Alexander Hulpke.